# Know if someone can receive a Push notification (for Journey Builder)

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobilepush

My question seems to be quite simple...
In a Journey, how can I create a split between:

- those who are able to receive a Push Notification
- those who can't (and they'll receive an email)

I don't know what data I would have to check. I thought I would use a dataview which would allow me to update a field in my Contacts' Data Extension but I can't find it neither.

Could you please help me ?

Thanks in advance !

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at the state of opted-in in the MobilePush Demographics in Contacts.  If a device is opted-in then you know that: 1) it is registered, 2) it has a push token and 3) the user has accepted the push permission.

Comment: Hi Bill, yes sure, that's the best way ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 2):

In a decision split, you could use contact data in Mobile Push Demographics/Subscription where option status = Opted In

[image]

Comment: Hi EazyE, thank you for this screenshot, it seems to be the good way to do it !